# How can I decode an utf-8 encoded string in JavaScript?

Tags: python, node.js, json, api

I am making a REST API project that gets data from a python script and prints it via node js. The data is sent from the python script to node js with the following code:

```
json_dump = json.dumps(data)
print(data.encode("utf-8", "replace"))
```

And js gets the data with the following code:

```
PythonShell.run('script.py', options, function (err, data) {
   if (err) throw err;
   res.json(JSON.parse(data));
});
```

But I get the following error:

```
Unexpected token b in JSON at position 0
```

The JSON arrives correctly but starts with a 'b' and many characters are not getting printed or gets printed like this: "\xf0\x9f\xa4\x91". What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `.encode("utf-8", "replace")`. This converts the string to a [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) object (the representation starts with the `b"..."`)

```
json_dump = json.dumps(data)
print(json_dump)
```

Comment: In the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout) it says the character encoding of stdout is platform dependant. So print might not emit utf8.

Comment: If I remove that it gives me the following error: PythonShellError: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f911' in position 11:

Comment: @GiulianoCrescimbeni Have you noticed that you wrote `print(data.encode("utf-8", "replace"))` instead of `print(json_dump.encode("utf-8", "replace"))`? I initially made the same mistake in my answer.

Comment: @Sven Ebert You were right, that resolved the problem